# Common Lisp's PROGV in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Common Lisp has a function called [progv](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progv.htm), which establishes dynamic bindings for a form given a list of symbols and values. I'm for something similar for Clojure. I'm pretty sure this doesn't exist in the core language. I'm wondering what my best option would be.

Comment: [binding](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding) does not do what you want?

Comment: this? https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/7ea70da82e42416864e2f97e3d314aced34af682/src/clojure/contrib/pprint/pprint_base.clj#L104

Comment: the richhickey/clojure ... repos are obsolete, look at the clojure github organization

Answer (score 3):

here's an example using binding:

```
user> (def ^:dynamic add +)
#'user/add
user> (binding [add -]
        (add 42 41))
1
```

because there is an efficiency cost to dynamic binding, recent versions of clojure require you to add metadata 
to each symbol that expects to be dynamically bound.

binding is just a wrapper around the functions `push-thread-bindings` and `pop-thread-bindings`, so if you want to build such binding dynamically you can call these functions yourself like so:

```
user> (defn with-alternate-addition [number1 number2 addition-function]
        (push-thread-bindings {#'add addition-function})
        (try
          (add number1 number2)
          (finally (pop-thread-bindings))))
 #'user/with-alternate-addition
 user> (with-alternate-addition 42 41 -)
 1
```

just make sure you get the pushes and pops right or things get *really* hard to debug.

Comment: What if I don't know the symbols at compile-time?

Comment: This actually isn't what I'm looking for. Here's a crude snippet of what I've got in mind. http://pastebin.com/51cKNgWz -- Instead I get errors with how I'm giving it `q`. `(var q)` doesn't work either.

Comment: for your example there let needs to be a var with the dynamic metadata key set to true.  if you include the desired output (and perhaps put these examples into your question) it will be easier to give an example.

Comment: I'm trying to port http://norvig.com/paip/patmatch.lisp, which contains pattern matching code whereby you could submit something like (pat-match ('(q u) . '(1 2)) and it would return that q = 1; u = 2. PROGV was used to allow evaluation using boolean logic